# Need Help writing a simple Apex Class to invoke default email template for Case Mgt

Tags: apex

I was pointed here by someone on the Success Community.  I need a simple APEX Class that will pull in one single default email template for my case management team. When they click on the email action button, I want a default email template to appear first (since most will use the default) and then i want them to be able to select other options thru the normal template folders if they wish to chose some other template.

The source code I was pointed to, as simple as it is, is even too complex for what I need.  Can I get some assistance on how to simplify the code to just pull in a default template called "Default Case Email Template". (I am not versed in writing Apex code at all).

**Here is what i was provided - need to dumb it down (dont need to look at Case Status or Case Reason for our needs. Literally just need to pull in the single default email template):**

```
global class SmartTemplateLoader implements Support.EmailTemplateSelector {
    // Empty constructor
    global SmartTemplateLoader() {    }
    // The main interface method
    global ID getDefaultEmailTemplateId(ID caseId) {
        // Select the case we're interested in, choosing any fields that are relevant to our decision
        Case c = [SELECT Status, Reason FROM Case WHERE Id=:caseId];

        Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c conf = null;
        List<Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c> confs = null;

        // get template from case status + case reason
        confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c WHERE Case_Status__c = :c.status and Case_Reason__c = :c.reason];
        if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
            conf = confs[0];
            System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
        }

        // get template from case status
        if (conf==null) {
            confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c WHERE Case_Status__c = :c.status];
            if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
                conf = confs[0];
                System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
            }
        }
        // get template from case reason
        confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c WHERE Case_Reason__c = :c.reason];
        if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
            conf = confs[0];
            System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
        }

        // get default template 
        if (conf==null) {
            confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c WHERE Case_Status__c = '' AND Case_Reason__c = ''];
            if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
                conf = confs[0];
                System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
            }
        }

        if (conf==null) {
            System.debug('no template!');
            return null;
        }

        // get the template ID
        List<EmailTemplate> ets = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = :conf.Template_Name__c];
        //Return the ID of the template selected
        if (!ets.isEmpty()) {
            EmailTemplate et = ets[0];
            System.debug('template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c + ' -- id: ' + et.id);
            return et.id;
        }
        System.debug('No template with the name: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!! 
D-

Answer (score 2):

So you're asking that in EVERY situation, the same email template is used? I have included that code below, but I have to ask why you want to use the same email template for EVERY case status and reason value. I removed all the code that refers to reason and status - I have not tested it, and I can't predict what will happen if there is no template in the org, but it will work.

You should also update your test code, though I have a feeling that you'll get the same coverage, as the test code will be more comprehensive than your needs.

Enjoy!

```
global class SmartTemplateLoader implements Support.EmailTemplateSelector {
    // Empty constructor
    global SmartTemplateLoader() {    }
    // The main interface method
    global ID getDefaultEmailTemplateId(ID caseId) {
        // Select the case we're interested in, choosing any fields that are relevant to our decision
        Case c = [SELECT Status, Reason FROM Case WHERE Id=:caseId];

        Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c conf = null;
        List<Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c> confs = null;

        // get ONLY template 
        if (conf==null) {
            confs = [SELECT Template_Name__c FROM Smart_Template_Loader_Conf__c LIMIT 1];
            if (!confs.isEmpty()) {
                conf = confs[0];
                System.debug('got template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);
            }
        }

        if (conf==null) {
            System.debug('no template!');
            return null;
        }

        // get the template ID
        List<EmailTemplate> ets = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = :conf.Template_Name__c];
        //Return the ID of the template selected
        if (!ets.isEmpty()) {
            EmailTemplate et = ets[0];
            System.debug('template: ' + conf.Template_Name__c + ' -- id: ' + et.id);
            return et.id;
        }
        System.debug('No template with the name: ' + conf.Template_Name__c);

        return null;
    }
}
```